# php insert into javascript works under php5 but not php7

Tags: javascript, php

This snippet worked in php5.6, but not in php7.

```
mp3: <script language = "php"> echo "\"" . $MP3FILE . "\"";</script>
```

The error is:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(I have confirmed that php7 is functioning and processing php files on my server.)

The site is:
[DNSpanishEnglish.php](http://professorbeautiful.org/DN/DNSpanishEnglish.php)
where it works under php5.6.
Here's the whole statement, just for context.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jQ_jP").jPlayer( {
          ready: function () {
                  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                         mp3: <script language = "php"> echo "\"" . $MP3FILE . "\"";</script>
                // Defines the mp3 url
          });
         startingTime = 45;
         //endingTime = $(this).jPlayer("status", "duration");
         //myAlert( "  endingTime is " + endingTime);
                  $(this).jPlayer("play", 45);  // THIS WORKS!!!!!
                  //$(this).jPlayer("play").jPlayer("stop").jPlayer("playHead", ).jPlayer.status.currentTime);
                  //$(this).jPlayer("playHead", {time: 50});
                  //$(this).jPlayer("play" , { time: 45 }); // works (required for auto-play), but the time args doesnt work.
          //  $(this).jPlayer("playHeadTime" , { time: 45000 });
         $("#jQ_jP").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
                  // Add a listener to report the time play began
                  //myAlert("HELLO from jplayer_1" +
                         //"Play began at time = " +
                  //     event.jPlayer.status.currentTime
                                  //);  // OK, this is happening.
                  //$("#jQ_jP").playHead(50); //doesnt work.
                  $("#jQ_jP").playHeadTime(45000);
                        // milliseconds. doesnt work.
         });
         $("#jQ_jP").playHeadTime(5000); // doesnt work.
          } // End of "ready". No semicolon here!
 });
});
```

Comment: Why `<script language="php">`?  Why not `<?php`? Or even better, `<?=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen due to the newer version of PHP7 remove these tag supports. you can use standard tags instead of it like  or .
Hope this will help you.
[image: From PHP official Website]

Comment: Thank you! That works.  I wrote a note to self from 2011 that <? does not work, only <?php.  I don't know that's still true.

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable elsewhere in php and you can use it in that script.

**PHP**

```
$MP3FILE = <?php echo $MP3fileLink ?>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jQ_jP").jPlayer( {
          ready: function () {
                  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                         mp3: $MP3FILE 
                // Defines the mp3 url
          });
         startingTime = 45;
         //endingTime = $(this).jPlayer("status", "duration");
         //myAlert( "  endingTime is " + endingTime);
                  $(this).jPlayer("play", 45);  // THIS WORKS!!!!!
                  //$(this).jPlayer("play").jPlayer("stop").jPlayer("playHead", ).jPlayer.status.currentTime);
                  //$(this).jPlayer("playHead", {time: 50});
                  //$(this).jPlayer("play" , { time: 45 }); // works (required for auto-play), but the time args doesnt work.
          //  $(this).jPlayer("playHeadTime" , { time: 45000 });
         $("#jQ_jP").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
                  // Add a listener to report the time play began
                  //myAlert("HELLO from jplayer_1" +
                         //"Play began at time = " +
                  //     event.jPlayer.status.currentTime
                                  //);  // OK, this is happening.
                  //$("#jQ_jP").playHead(50); //doesnt work.
                  $("#jQ_jP").playHeadTime(45000);
                        // milliseconds. doesnt work.
         });
         $("#jQ_jP").playHeadTime(5000); // doesnt work.
          } // End of "ready". No semicolon here!
 });
});
```